# How to separately add a header row while loading a parquet file?

Tags: python, dataframe, parquet

While handling csv files we can say:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names=header_list, dtype=dtype_dict)
```

Above would create a dataframe with headers as header_list and dtypes as of the dtype_dict

Can we do something similar with `pd.read_parquet()` ?

My issue involves **passing in headers separately** and would thus not be available in the "test.csv"
Another way to bypass it could be to move the entire data in df downwards by 1 (including shifting headers into rows) and then replacing the header with header_list (if it's even possible?)

Is there an optimal solution to my issue?
I'm not too familiar with parquet so any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we do something similar with pd.read_parquet() ?

parquet files contain some metadata, including the name of the columns and their types. So there is no need to pass this information when loading the data.

Comment: When generating a parquet file, if the data source does not have the headers it would assume the first row as headers, which is the issue. Can be replicated if you have a csv without headers and make that into a parquet.